# How to retrieve geographical location from users using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, api, openlayers, reverse-geocoding

I'm programming in [Angular](https://angular.io/) with [Openlayers](http://openlayers.org/) library.
I want to use this API : https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/api (the page is in french so I will explain the purpose)

The goal of this API is on the one hand to search some adresses on a map while building GeoJSON files and on the other hand to use a reverse geocoding. This is why I need geographical location from the user.

For example this request : `http 'https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q=8 bd du port'` will return all the streets in the world answering to the name "8 bd du port"

So I want to use the reverse geocoding and create a request like this : `http 'https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=user_lon&lat=user_lat'`

It is the best way to proceed ? I don't want to use an another API like Google one

Comment: No duplicate, I don't want to use Google API, I search a way to do this with Angular

Comment: The most upvoted answer indicates to use the browser's geolocation API. It only mentions google API as a workaround

Comment: This question is not answering mine, I want to know the best way to implements location with Angular (this is not the case in this post because I know that Angular is different)

Comment: You question is about retrieval geographical position from users. Angular runs in the browser. The browser provides a geolocation API. I'm not sure what you want more...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the HTML standard Geolocation api for this.

```
  getLocation(): void{
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position)=>{
          const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
          const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          this.callApi(longitude, latitude);
        });
    } else {
       console.log("No support for geolocation")
    }
  }

  callApi(Longitude: number, Latitude: number){
    const url = `https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=${Longitude}&lat=${Latitude}`
    //Call API
  }
```

Comment: With this code I have several errors, the problem is coming from the `:` character

Comment: Are you using angular or angularjs?

Comment: I'm using Angular 6

Comment: Im not sure then, that works perfectly with Angular 6, Look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-ax8ued?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I was mistaken excuse me, ok then I'll try this, thank you !